# How do I add together the numbers of a requested integer/number or should it be a string?

Tags: python, jython

This is an extra question that I do not get points for and I have tried to work it out for hours. I am working in Jython.

```
def  sumOfId():
  number = requestNumber ("Enter Student ID Here")
```

Now I want to add the separate numbers that make up the `id` together.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Take the string character by character and add it up after parsing to int.

```
def sum_of_id(student_id):
    sum = 0
    for num in student_id:
        sum += int(num)
    # print('Sum = %d' % sum)
    return sum
```

Comment: Can you pls tell me how i get there, for example, how would you tell me to do this if you didnt know the numbers 1234. I have requested them then, i need to do something like identify them, i hope im making sense.

Comment: Have sum_of_id function accept a parameter 'student_id'. You can use the rest of the code above to calculate and return the sum. Edited my answer for clarity as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
def sum_digits(s):
    return sum(int(digit) for digit in s)

number = requestNumber("Enter Student ID Here: ")
print(sum_digits(number))
```

By removing the prompt for the student ID, `sum_digits()` is a more generic function that can operate on any sequence including strings, lists, tuples, dictionary keys, etc. Provided that the items in the sequence can be converted to an integer with `int()`, it will return the sum of the items.

The function uses a generator expression to iterate over the items in the sequence converting each into an integer, producing a new sequence which is then passed to sum to perform the addition of all its items.